# What is the Rule of thumb for alerting on`mysql.innodb.buffer_pool_reads / mysql.innodb.buffer_pool_read_requests`?

Tags: innodb, monitoring, buffer-pool, alerts

Is there a rule of thumb for monitoring `mysql.innodb.buffer_pool_reads / mysql.innodb.buffer_pool_read_requests`?

I am using the following formula, but I'm starting to think it's too sensitive.

```
(mysql.innodb.buffer_pool_reads / mysql.innodb.buffer_pool_read_requests) * 100 > 0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that if

```
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads / Innodb_buffer_pool_requests > 2%
```

then either the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` needs raising, or something else needs tweaking.

A poll of several servers showed that about 10% were over that 2%.  (About 20% were over your cutoff of 0.2%)

The ratio is less important for SSD drives than for HDD.

If you would like more analysis, http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning